# What is the correct way of creating a defensive copy in a constructor

Tags: java, multithreading

I have the following private collection:

```
final private ConcurrentHashMap<Book,BookLog> booklogMap;
```

I currently make a copy in the constructor like this:

```
this.booklogMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<Book, BookLog>(booklogMap);
```

Is this the correct way of creating a defensive copy in the constructor?  If not, how do you properly make a defensive copy of a thread-safe collection?

Comment: What about using an unchangeable wrapper instead? http://stackoverflow.com/a/4262459/13422

Comment: @ZanLynx - I tried that, but it kept giving me cast errors, could you show me how?

Comment: I've never tried it on a Concurrent anything, might have to experiment.

Comment: If you want to capture the state of the map at the time the ctor is called, you do need to make a copy. Using an unchangeable wrapper will just keep your class from modifying the list. If other code changes the list, then your class will see those changes and your class will have to have to worry about concurrent changes to the list.

Comment: @pcarter - how would I do it for a concurrenthashmap?

Comment: @pcarter - I've declared it final by the way

Comment: The code you have above makes a copy of the list. Since your values are immutable that's all you have to do. However, you should use synchronization to make sure the list isn't changed while you ctor is making the copy. After the copy is made, your class can access the copy without worrying about other code changing it.

Comment: @pcarter - How would I do that?

Comment: @pcarter synchronizing in this ctor is not going to help if the caller is going to change it without using the same lock

Comment: @AnnabelleRosemond are you trying to protect against the caller changing the collection while the ctor is making a copy?

Comment: I want to understand defensive copying when it comes to thread safe collections.

Comment: @AnnabelleRosemond - That depends on the other code that is using the original map. There should be some object that is being used as a lock for accessing the original. That lock needs to be held when making the copy. Either before calling the ctor or inside the ctor.

Comment: @pcarter- there is no code using the original map, the getter returns a new collection, that's it

Comment: @AnnabelleRosemond defensive copy if I understand righ is used in getters so that the caller may not break encapsulation. There is no need to make a copy in the constructor if you are creating it in the constructor in the first place. If your callers are well-behaved then `Collections.unmodifiableMap` may be quicker than copying

Comment: @AnnabelleRosemond - If no other code is using the original map, why do you need to make a defensive copy? They way your example is written, it looks like the `booklogMap` (without the `this`) is a parameter passed to the ctor. One would assume it is passed in because other code is using it; otherwise it would just be a private member of your class.

Comment: @pcarter - I have a getter and I was reading about defensive copying, they said to apply it to Collections/dates, because you should modify it using the getter. Anyways, I've given up with this class.

Comment: @pcarter If the original map is thread-safe (that is, it works correctly even if elements are added and removed during iteration) then there is no need for synchronization. If it isn't, then synchronization won't save you either.

Comment: @biziclop - How would you properly create a defensive copy of a thread-safe collection?

Comment: @pcarter: Correct me if I'm wrong but Concurrent objects in Java don't need synchronization. They're built to be accessed from multiple threads. Right?

Comment: @ZanLynx - Yes, I was thinking about general Maps, iteration of a ConncurrentHashMap is thread safe.

Answer (score 5):

this.booklogMap = new ConcurrentHashMap(booklogMap);

This is a Copy Constructor. Almost All standard Collection and Map implementations have one, and it's usually the simplest way to clone a simple structure. This will work fine as long as Book and BookLog are immutable.